# Web Part Activation Error

Tags: web-part, custom

I am developing a web part and suddenly receive this error when activating it from site settings.

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolution' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition'.

I cannot get this cleared up even after retracting and removing a number of times.
Thanks

Comment: are you doing anything in a feature receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I added the solution ID to the Activation Dependency list instead of the Feature ID.

Comment: Isn't this almost exactly what Laurie suggested?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like SharePoint is trying to activate your feature using a SolutionID instead of a FeatureID. Make sure you did not use the same guid as both a FeatureID and a SolutionID.

Comment: Those are quite different and have not changed at all.  The project has deployed more than once before but now all of a sudden this error.